# Как сделать так чтобы при разворачиваемости div блок на все строку?

Tags: jquery, html

У меня такая проблема, допустим вот пример

```js
$('.header').click(function(){
  if($(this).hasClass('expand')){
     $(this).closest('table').find('.header').addClass('expand');
    $(this).closest('table').find('.child').remove();
    $(this).removeClass('expand').after('<div class="child"><p>blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah</p><p>Привет мир</p></div>');
  } else {
    $(this).addClass('expand').parent().find('.child').remove();
  }
});
```

```css
table, tr, td, th
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
.header:hover{
  cursor: pointer
}
.header .sign:after{
  content: '-'
}
.header.expand .sign:after{
  content: '+'
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border='0'>
  <tr>
    <th>Класс</th>
    <th>Код</th>
    <th>Город</th>
    <th>Дата создание</th>
    <th>Дата редактирование</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class='header expand'>
    <td><span class='sign'></span> Мебель</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Казань</td>
    <td>2017-03-10 10:00:00</td>
    <td>2017-03-10 10:30:00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='header expand'>
    <td><span class='sign'></span> Электроника</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Москва</td>
    <td>2017-03-15 09:15:00</td>
    <td>2017-03-15 10:30:00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='header expand'>
    <td><span class='sign'></span> Бытовая химия</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Санк-Петербург</td>
    <td>2017-03-10 10:00:00</td>
    <td>2017-03-10 10:30:00</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Когда разворачиваешь строку. то весь div блок равняется под столбец, а мне нужно чтобы она шла под всю строку. А то как-то некрасиво получается и если там будут 3 колонки в блоке, то таблица 1 столбец будет вообще громадная.
А мне бы хотелось, чтобы таблица сохраняла свои пропорции

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавляйте в таблицу строку с одной ячейкой, перекрывающей пять существующих.

```
$(this).removeClass('expand')
  .after('<tr class="child"><td colspan="5"><p>blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah</p><p>Привет мир</p></td></tr>');
```

> Там только есть минус, в том, что если подключить bootstrp и
>   использовать класс col-xs-, то не совсем удобно выходит. https://jsfiddle.net/hollanditkzn/x2bcukw7/12/

Поставьте не два `col-xs-4`, а два `col-xs-6` - общее количество бутстраповских колонок должно равняться 12-ти.

Comment: Там только есть минус, в том, что если подключить bootstrp и использовать класс col-xs-, то не совсем удобно выходит. вот пример https://jsfiddle.net/x2bcukw7/8/ Это последняя что меня волнует

Comment: или td использовать?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hollanditkzn/x2bcukw7/12/ вот должен быть корректный пример быть. То есть там текст идет некорректно

Comment: Или там лучше добавить css word-break: break-all;